# How to click an empty google sheet cell and get the real time, NOW()?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

[image: Time Sheet]

I work for a transportation company and What I am trying to achieve is that every time a driver login or mobiles over the two-way radio, I want to click the empty cell and get the real time. I know there is a Now() function, in google sheets but if I use that all cells will have the same value, I want to get the current time when I click the empty cell.

I used the script editor to create buttons for a workaround that will show me in and out times, but I want to keep the original format of the sheet, here is the code below:

```
function setValue(cellName, value){
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
    }

    function getValue(cellName){
      return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValue();
    }

    function getNextRow(){
      return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow() + 1;
    }

    function setGeorge(){
      setValue('M1','George,CSH2501')
    }
    function setTerry(){
      setValue('M1','Terry,CSH2502')
    }

    function setDavid(){
      setValue('M1','David,PSH3502')
    }

    function setSandra(){
      setValue('M1','Sandra,PSH3508')
    }
    function setElioCalle(){
      setValue('M1','ElioCalle,PSH3504')
    }
    function setWarren(){
      setValue('M1','Warren,PSH3501')
    }
    function setShu(){
      setValue('M1','Shu,PSH3503')
    }
    function setPaul(){
      setValue('M1','Paul Prkash,PSH3507')
    }
    function setMei(){
      setValue('M1','Mei Tsang,PSH3506')
    }
    function setJames(){
      setValue('M1','James Clark,PSH3505')
    }
    function setElvira(){
      setValue('M1','Elvira,PSH3509')
    }
    function addRecord(b, c, d){
      var row = getNextRow();
      setValue('A'+ row, b);
      setValue('B'+ row, c);
      setValue('C'+ row, d);
    }
    function punchIn(){
    addRecord(getValue('M1'), new Date(), 'IN');
    }
    function punchOut(){
    addRecord(getValue('M1'), new Date(), 'Out');
    }
```

And the results are this:
[image]

Comment: Not sure if you can do that. As a workaround put `'=NOW()` in all cells then remove the `'` when needed

Comment: That is a really great idea, I like that and it much less tedious than typing out the time everytime someone logs in, however, is it possible to create a radio button with an (IN & OUT) functionality as below:

Answer (score 0):

=Now() is a volatile function, every time you change some data in the spreadsheet or refresh the sheet excel recalculates it. The only way to overcome is through a script, I created buttons using the drawing tool and assigned functions punchIn and punchOut for every time a driver mobiles and clears:

```
function punchIn(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var now = new Date();
  sheet.getRange('E3').setValue(now);
}

function punchOut(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var now = new Date();
  sheet.getRange('H3').setValue(now);
}
```

The only thing was I have to do this for every cell and every button as you can see from the image below. If there is a way to simplify the code any suggestion would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I thought this would work, however Now() is a volatile function and when you enter other cells value, the cells time change to the current time

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays it's possible to insert a timestamp when clicking a cell by using the `onSelectionChange` simple trigger.

The following example will add a timestamp to any cell / range selected

```
function onSelectionChange(e) { 
  e.range.setValue(new Date());
}
```

You can control on which cells the timestamp be added, i.e., by using if-statements and the event object.

- After adding onSelectionChange trigger you have to reload the spreadsheet to make it start working.
- When opening a spreadsheet from Google Drive or Google Sheets apps, the default active cell is the first cell of the first sheet, onSelectionChange will not run in this case but if you use a range link , i.e. `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/spreadheetId/edit#gid=0&range=I5:I9`, onSelectionChange will run.